# General solution of the equation $x(\frac{dy}{dx})^2+\left(y-x\right)\frac{dy}{dx}\:-y=0$ is

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> General solution of the equation 
>   $$x\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2+\left(y-x\right)\frac{dy}{dx}\:-y=0 
> $$is

Option are as follows:

$a)\qquad (x-y+c)(xy-c)=0$

$b)\qquad (x+y+c)(xy-c)=0$

$c)\qquad (x-y+c)(x^2+y^2-c)=0$

$d)\qquad (x-y+c)(x^2+y^2-c)=0$

Answer (score 4):

The equations of such forms are Clairauts equations.Hint let $\frac{dy}{dx}=p$ we have $xp^2+(y-x)p-y=0$ thus $$p=\frac{(x-y)\pm\sqrt{y^2-2xy+x^2-4(x)(-y)}}{2x}=\frac{(x-y)\pm(y+x)}{2x}$$ now continue from here resubstitute $p$ and solve the two differential equations to see which gives the answer. Also include your effort in the question itself so that the question attracts more attention.

Comment: Can you give a reference or link that this general form is known under the name "Clairaut", and not only the special form $y=px+f(p)$?

Comment: Sorry I wrongly wrote that. It's d'Alemberts equation actually .had it been $-(y-x)dy/dx$ then equation would have turned to clairauts form with $y(x)=xy'(x)$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$\frac{dy}{dx}=1$$ or $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{y(x)}{x}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$x\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2+\left(y-x\right)\frac{dy}{dx}\:-y=0$$
$$\implies xp^2+(y-x)p-y=0\qquad \text{where}\quad p\equiv \frac{dy}{dx}$$

$$\implies xp(p-1)+y(p-1)=0$$
$$\implies (p-1)(y+xp)=0$$
$$\implies \text{either}\quad y+xp=0\qquad \text{or}\quad p-1=0$$

$$p-1=0\implies x-y+c=0\qquad \text{and}$$
$$y+xp=0\implies xy-c=0$$

General solution is $$(x-y+c)(xy-c)=0$$